# SSIS 2012 - Web Service Task - Output Exceptions

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2012, ssis, sendmail, ssis-2012

I've got a Web Service Task in my Control Flow.

The actual Web Service type is void.  For testing purposes, the Web Service just throws a new Exception, with a message.

I've got the task outputting to a variable User::ServiceResponse

The Failure path goes to a Send Mail Task, which uses the variable User::ServiceResponse... however, the email received does not contain any text.

When the package executes, the Immediate Window does show a long error, which in part contains my exception message. "Adams Error Message" towards the very end.

```
SSIS package "....\WebProfile.dtsx" starting.
Error: 0xC002F304 at SVC, Web Service Task: An error occurred with the following error message:
"Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebserviceTaskException:
The Web Service threw an error during method execution.
The error is: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
Server was unable to process request. --->
System.Exception: Adams Error Message
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---.
```

Without writing a lot of custom script... how can I get the exceptions from my Web Service Task into the Send Mail Task?

Comment: I guess since it failed (raised an excepption) it didn't populate ServiceResponse. You might be able to use SSIS _expressions_ (inside the properties of the mail task) to grab the SSIS error message and populate the email body with it.

Comment: @ElectricLlama Thanks for the direction on that, I'll start reseraching expressions.  Any pointers or tips while I get started?

Comment: Looks like expressions are not an option as you can't access the package stdout from inside the expression editor. However, given that _any_ error (not just web service) will appear at the command line, perhaps it's better to drive your email off the command line, not internally in your package? I know you don't want to do a lot of custom script but setting up blat.exe to pass on the output of DTEXEC.EXE shouldn't be that difficult. If this interests you we can explore this option further.

Comment: Further to this, failure emailing is built into SQL Agent, so if you run your pacakge from there you can set it up to send an email (possibly with the full package stdout). Yet another way is using _Event Handlers_ in SSIS to capture an error event inside your web task event and send an email from in there.... but it's custom code.